# Array filtration in sqlalchemy

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I want to filtering my array field in this way:
I have array my_array {'one', 'two', 'three'} and i want to filtering data by list of value ['one', 'two'].
So if i have 'one' and 'two' in my array so i get this data. I tried to realize this with sqlalchemy 'contains'.

```
 result = session.query(Alert).filter(Alert.tag_list.contains(tag_list)).filter(
                Alert.date_create >= datetime.datetime.utcnow() - datetime.timedelta(minutes=c.ALERT_TIME_LIVE)).order_by(Alert.person_id).limit(
            per_page).offset((page - 1) * per_page).all()
```

My db type `from sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql import ARRAY` and `tag_list = Column(ARRAY(String(50), dimensions=1))`.
But when i try to complete my query i received empty list even if two tags exist in my array.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bp41e.png)

In my picture i have tag 'test', but when use 'contains(['test', 'test1'])' it returns [].

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Can you provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)? Does session.query(Alert).filter(Alert.tag_list.contains(tag_list)).all() also produce an empty list?

Comment: Edit my question.